# InlineCms - Could use some help setting up

Tags: php, scripting, content-management-system

Im trying to setup [www.inlinecms.com](http://inlinecms.com) cms on my hosting.
I uploaded the contents of the zip folder but its seems to be trying to find scripts from the server root and not the directory of the cms.

I've tried to fix this but to avail, I manage to get it working but when it was installed it then couldnt find the site because of what i did.

Would be greatful if someone could get this working, have setup a test site [www.jskelton.co.uk](http://jskelton.co.uk) so you can see the source code.

Bootstrap.php

```
<?php
```

/**
 * InlineCMS v1.0.1
 * Copyright 2016, InstantSoft
 *
 * @author Vladimir E. Obukhov
 * @package InlineCMS
 * @link http://inlinecms.com
 * @license http://inlinecms.com/license
 */

```
session_start();

define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
define('ROOT_URL', str_replace(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/'), '', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', ROOT_PATH)));

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

require_once ROOT_PATH . '/app/loader.php';

spl_autoload_register(array('\InlineCMS\Loader', 'autoLoad'));

\InlineCMS\Core\Config::load();
\InlineCMS\Core\Request::load();
```

Comment: My best guess is that the root of the project isn't configured right. So instead of using your webroot it uses the system's root. But I'm not familiair with inline cms and wouldn't know where to change that

Comment: Im just after a simple cms for clients, that I can import or integrate static html and this looked great apart from the fact it doesn't work lol.

Comment: Ok I got it I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This got the JS and CSS files loading properly for me even though I haven't had much luck so far getting the CMS to work with anything other than the demo template.

*bootstrap.php*

`//  define('ROOT_URL', str_replace(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/'), '', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', ROOT_PATH)));`
`define('ROOT_URL', '');`